# uninitialized constant Capybara::DSL

Tags: selenium-webdriver, capybara

I can't seem to figure out why this doesn't work, I don't know what else to say as I'm sure this should be quite simple.

```
>> pry
[1] pry(main)> require 'capybara'
^[[A=> true
[2] pry(main)> require 'selenium-webdriver'
=> true
[3] pry(main)> include Capybara::DSL
NameError: uninitialized constant Capybara::DSL
from (pry):3:in `__pry__'
```

Any help would be really appreciated as this little issue is driving me mad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get access to `Capybara::DSL` you need to `require 'capybara/dsl'` (instead of just 'capybara') as documented [here](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#using-the-dsl-elsewhere)

Comment: Why has that proven so difficult for me to find?
Thanks for the help.